# Pandas compare method to show differences and keep only one column equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have 2 dataframes with the same shape and 20 columns each one.
I want to compare them and obviously the easiest way to do it is to use pandas compare. Assuming that one column never changes and it's equal in both dataframes how can I use compare with keep shame and keep equal but to only one column? Sometimes only few columns changes and I don't want to have displayed redundant information.

As the title mentioned, I used pandas compare.

```
NUMBER STATUS CASE1 CAS2 CODE_A
123    Active 40    50   V045J
456    Active 40    50   V0424
789    Active 40    50   V044R



NUMBER STATUS CASE1 CAS2 CODE_A
123    Active 40    50   V45J
456    Active 80    50   V424
789    Active 40    50   V44R
```

NUMBER column doesn't change

The result should be like this

```
NUMBER CASE1         CODE_A
       self other    self  other
123    NaN  NaN      V045J V45J
456    40   80       V0424 V424
789    Nan  NaN      V044R V44R
```

Comment: Can you provide snippet examples of your data, and the output you expect? (See the SO (Stack Overflow) "Help Center"/FAQ on "How to ask good questions" and use markdown for formatting your code/data, and/or provide screenshots). It's not totally clear what you want as your output exactly; `pandas.DataFrame.compare` may actually _not_ be the easiest way to accomplish want you want

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JohnCollins I hope it's clear now

Comment: I provided a posted answer in response. Seems to work pretty straightforwardly to me. Providing your actual source code (which creates the dataframes, ideally) would be even better, but I'll upvote for the improvement in your question :) Let me/us know if you need more help, specifically.

Comment: @JohnCollins I need also the column NUMBER. The reason why I need this is that I need to see for which NUMBER the values changed between these 2 dataframes. The source comes from a database and I don't have access to the method which creates the dataframe.

Comment: I see. No worries. I expanded my answer. If you don't want the number column to be set to the index, then simply  remove the line I show which sets the index.

Comment: @JohnCollins thank you. I never thought about adding a new column or setting the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the following code:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array(
        [
            [123, "Active", 40, 50, "V045J"],
            [456, "Active", 40, 50, "V0424"],
            [789, "Active", 40, 50, "V044R"],
        ]
    ),
    columns=["NUMBER", "STATUS", "CASE1", "CAS2", "CODE_A"],
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array(
        [
            [123, "Active", 40, 50, "V445J"],
            [456, "Active", 80, 50, "V4424"],
            [789, "Active", 40, 50, "V444R"],
        ]
    ),
    columns=["NUMBER", "STATUS", "CASE1", "CAS2", "CODE_A"],
)

df1.compare(df2)
```

gives:

[image: df.compare output]

If your concern is with persisting the `NUMBER` column, something like this may achieve what you are trying to do:

```py
df3 = df1.compare(df2)
df3['NUMBER'] = df1.NUMBER
df3.set_index('NUMBER', inplace=True)
df3
```

which creates the following dataframe structure:
[image: dataframe compare result with number column index]

Answer (score 0):

#### You didn't submit a code example, but based off you explained here is what I came up with.

*again, with a code example a better solution can be given*

```py
import pandas as pd

# Example DataFrame df1
data1 = {
    'common_column': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'col1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    'col2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    'col3': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

# Example DataFrame df2 (similar to df1 but with some differences in 'col1' and 'col3')
data2 = {
    'common_column': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'col1': [11, 20, 35, 40, 55],
    'col2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    'col3': [100, 250, 300, 410, 500]
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# Perform the comparison
comparison_result = df1.compare(df2, keep_shape=True, keep_equal=True)

# Display the differences
print(comparison_result)
```

You can refer to pandas docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html)